# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException only for some users

Tags: android, android-resources

Very strange issue, I have a splash screen that just loads a drawable called `background_splash`. The drawable is a `layer-list`. The splash works fine for me, works fine for the majority of my users, on the hundreds of thousands, but every release I get an exception report on Crashlytics for a few users because it can not find the resource. So on my latest beta I did a test and put this on the `Application` `onCreate`.

```
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.background_splash);
```

And with that I actually get even more crashes. It still works for the majority, but for example out of 8k users that have tried the beta, 8 have crashed. Seems to be across different phones and manufacturers.

This is the crash:

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_splash.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080063
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:837)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:891)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:833)
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
       at myPackage.MyApp.onCreate(MyApp.java:913)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6056)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

I unzipped the bundle and the file is there, so I don't know what the issue is. Here is a screenshot of ls of the resources drawable folder of the bundle.

[image]

Edit: This is who it affected on the beta by loading the drawable on `onCreate`.

[image]

This is who it affected before the beta on the loading of the splash:

[image]

Comment: Is there a common Android version?

Comment: may be related to usage of apis in the xml file which are not present on older platforms or a density specific resource is missing.

Comment: No, android 6 through 8 mostly. I've tested on every android platform I support. The number of users having the crash is so small that it definitely doesn't affect an entire version or even manufacturer.

Comment: We have a small amount of similar crash background radiation in production. Our customer support is instructed to tell users with crashes to uninstall and reinstall the app. It works most of the time.

Comment: Interesting. I've never had a user with this issue actually contact me, at least not that I have been able to tell, so it could just be as simples as that. Thanks for letting me know I'm not alone.